# Scapy AttributeError on every call: 'module' object has no attribute '*'

Tags: python, scapy

I have installed Scapy from the package repos on my Ubuntu machine (Python 2.7), and I am trying to run this code from a file:

```
import scapy
dg = scapy.IP()
pcap = scapy.rdpcap("../tst/Http.cap")
scapy.send(IP())
```

Running gives the error,
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IP'`

Comment out the IP call on line 3 and running gives the error,
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rdpcap'`

Also comment out line 4 and you get,
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'send'`

Curously, this code fails when invoked with ''python '', but it works as expected when I manually enter each command into the Python shell. I have observed this behaviour on three fresh Python installs - two in Ubuntu, and one in Windows. Can anyone else see the cause of this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import Scapy into the global namespace.

From the [Scapy module documentation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html#overview) -

> Note: In Scapy v2 use from scapy.all import * instead of from scapy import *.

Also found in ["Using Scapy to build your own tools"](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/build_your_own_tools.html).

So your code should be -

```
from scapy.all import *

dg = IP()
pcap = rdpcap("../tst/Http.cap")
send(IP())
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've made that change, but the error persists.

Comment: Took another look and fixed something and now it's working. Thanks!